# SQLAlchemy returns unexpected results with limit/offset

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query that does multiple left joins and then performs a limit/offset for pagination purposes.  My problem is that the limit/offset appears to be applied to the *total* number of rows returned after all of the joins have been performed.  What I'd like is for the limit/offset to be applied to the number of ORM instances that I get back from the query.

Here's an example query:

```
result = session.query(A)\
.outerjoin(B)\
.outerjoin(C)\
.order_by(A.id)\
.offset(0).limit(100).all()
```

So if A has a one to many relationship with C via join table B, I might get N rows per row in A.  Is there something special I need to do so that the limit/offset is applied against the count of A instances instead of how many rows the joins produced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just how SQL works. [This article](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/) about the order of operations in an SQL  statement might be of interest. You could offset and limit in a subquery and join against that. [`Query.from_self()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_self) is handy in this particular situation, especially since it does automatic aliasing:

```
result = session.query(A)\
    .order_by(A.id)\
    .offset(0).limit(100)\
    .from_self()\
    .outerjoin(B)\
    .outerjoin(C)\
    .all()
```

Comment: You could explain the case more for a better understanding.