# sqlalchemy - Limit for joined table as if they where not joined

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy, and I want to get the following data from user and apply those operations in the order given to a table:

> keyword to filter the data with, column to order by, limit and page
>   number

now I have many tables. The majority "children" tables - a table that has no children - work. However I have a table with a lot of relationships of all kinds .. one to many on both sides, one to one and many to many

to achieve the above operations, I joined all the tables beforehand. filtering and ordering works fine but limit does not give me the wanted result

Join statement:

```
records = m.Activity.query.join(m.Event, m.Activity.events) \
            .join(m.DateLocation, m.Activity.date_locations) \
            .join(m.Goal, m.Activity.goals) \
            .join(m.Type, m.Activity.type)
```

filtering and ordering contains a lot of unnessecary information, basically something like this:

```
# filtering if column == event
records = records.filter(m.Event.name == keyword) 
# ordering if column == type and desc was chosen
records = records.order_by(m.Type.name.desc())
```

and finally limit and pagination:

```
records = records.limit(limit)
records = records.offset((page - 1) * limit)
```

Let me explain limit behavior vs what I want:

limit in this code works fine. since I joined all the tables it will return the number of joined row I gave it .. if the join resulted in extra 5 rows and I asked for limit 5 for example, it will return the first 5 regardless of the original table id

What I want is the limit behavior before joining. I only joined them to filter or order by them. after that when I say limit (5) I want to return the first 5 results with distinct ids

I tried the following(one at a time) but didn't work:

```
records = records.distinct(m.Activity.id).limit(limit)
records = records.group_by(m.Activity.id).limit(limit)
records = records.from_self().limit(limit)
```

I tried the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977257/sqlalchemy-returns-unexpected-results-with-limit-offset). It does work HOWEVER it limits the set of data BEFORE joining. which doesn't work in my case since I need to limit the filtered data

**EDIT:** The models:

```
EventsInActivities = db.Table(
    'events_in_activities',
    db.Column('activity_id', db.String, db.ForeignKey('activity.id')),
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
)


class Event(db.Model, BaseMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)


class Type(db.Model, BaseMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    activities = db.relationship("Activity", backref="type", lazy='dynamic')


class Goal(db.Model, BaseMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    activity_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('activity.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())


class DateLocation(db.Model, BaseMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    activity_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('activity.id'), primary_key=True)
    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    location = db.Column(db.String())


class Activity(db.Model, BaseMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('type.id'))
    date_locations = db.relationship("DateLocation", order_by='DateLocation.start_date', cascade="all, delete", backref="activity", lazy='dynamic')
    goals = db.relationship("Goal", cascade="all, delete", backref="activity", lazy='dynamic')
    events = db.relationship('Event', secondary=EventsInActivities, backref=db.backref('activities', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace at least some of the joins for filters with [EXISTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) subquery expressions, or [semijoins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_(%E2%8B%89)(%E2%8B%8A)) in a way. This way your query avoids producing multiple rows for single activity. It is ok to still join against `Type`, since it's a many to one relationship:

```
records = m.Activity.query.\
    join(m.Activity.type).\
    filter(m.Activity.events.any(name=keyword)).\
    filter(m.Activity.goals.any(name=...)).\
    filter(...).\
    order_by(m.Type.name.desc()).\
    limit(limit).\
    offset((page - 1) * limit)
```

Passing keyword arguments to [`any()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) is a similar shorthand as [`filter_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by). It accepts complex criterion expressions as well, as positional arguments.

The `distinct(m.Activity.id)`, or DISTINCT ON, should've worked as well, as long as you then use the results as a subquery, to which you then apply the ordering and limit:

```
records = m.Activity.query.\
    join(m.Activity.events).\
    join(m.Activity.date_locations).\
    join(m.Activity.goals).\
    filter(m.Event.name == keyword).\
    filter(...).\
    distinct(m.Activity.id).\
    from_self().\
    join(m.Activity.type).\
    order_by(m.Type.name.desc()).\
    limit(limit).\
    offset((page - 1) * limit)
```

Comment: it worked! thank you! for anyone interested I used the first solution is it goes better with the rest of my code

Comment: Just a quick question .. how would order_by work with goals for example?

Comment: That'd depend. Do all related goals share the same name per activity? If not, by which one would you order?

Comment: each activity has different goal .. the majority holds one goal but it is possible for an activity to have more than one. same goes for events. The real problem is date locations as each activity has easily +2 of these with distinct values. I would like to do something like ordering them all by the start date. and then take the distinct activity id and present them as "being ordered by the start date"

Comment: By "start date" do you mean you'd like to order by least `DateLocation.start_date` per `Activity`? That's a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem of sorts. All in all it's a bit unclear how you'd choose a `Goal` or `Event` from the respective groups by which you'd order activities, or I've misunderstood. Did you mean you'd like to eagerly load goals etc., sorted?

Comment: yes that is what I would like to do. lets say a certain activity has two date location .. the start date for the first is 11-07-2018 and the other is 19-07-2018. another activity's date location's start date is 13-07-2018. Now if I ordered by start date in descending manner, I would like to get the first activity then the second one; because even though the first start date is smaller than the second activity, the second start date for the activity is actually larger thus displaying first activity first

Comment: Thank you btw. I would probably do more research on the topic you suggested and then post a new question if I didn't know how to make them after that as I feel like I am going out of the topic